# C# - Filesystemwatcher to enable Timer

Tags: c#

**Hello All,**

//Pleas i have a simple Problem. I need, when Filesystemwatcher sees the File -after fsw start the Timer for Closing Application (Application will be Closed after 2 second, when is file created)//

**Thank you user "Never Quit" ***

Finaly i Have this "easy" Code :-)

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    System.Timers.Timer casovac = new System.Timers.Timer();
    int totalSeconds = 0;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        casovac.Interval = 1000;
        casovac.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(cas_elapsed);

    }
    void cas_elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
          totalSeconds++;

        if (totalSeconds == 3) 
        {
            casovac.Stop();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();

        fsw.Path = Application.StartupPath + "\\OUT\\";
        fsw.Filter = "file.exe";
        fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_changed);
        fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_changed);
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    private void fsw_changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        casovac.Start();         
    }




}
```

}

But Thank you All ;-)

Comment: "logical simple Problem", a what now? :)

Comment: you do not need both `.Start()` and `Enabled=true` -- they both do the same thing. Put a break point on `fsw_changed` to make sure it is called. Also, how do you define the timer? make sure you have subscribed to the `Tick` event and have set the correct interval.

Comment: By the way when you ask questions on SO, "here's some code, tell me what's wrong with it" is an antipattern. Please be very specific about what you expect to happen, and what really happens.

Comment: You should probably debug this, line by line, and come back with what you think happened, as opposed to what *should* happen.

Comment: Sorry for me Bad English, i have tried Edit me Code, nothing  
success. Timer Setting is Generate_members - True, Modifiers - Private, Interval - 2000

Comment: It is interesting When I give directly to                       private void fsw_changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
               Timer_end.Start(); 
               MessageBox.Show("Timer Activate");
            }                                                                    After Timer is starting normaly... (I see MessageBox "Test Timer"

Comment: It's still not clear what you're hoping to do. Your original post states *'when Filesystemwatcher sees the File -after fsw start the Timer'* (code suggests this is what happens). But then you also say *'when filesystemwatcher see the "file.exe", after 3 second Close Application'*. **There is no code to attempt this.** So what are you trying to do, and where are you struggling?

Comment: Just I edited the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to create one `FileSystemWatcher` which monitors your specified path and gives you an event when it founds "**file.exe**". As soon your program found this file timer get started and after several time(2 sec) your application get closed automatically. Right???

I've made demo which fulfill your requirement.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tim = new System.Timers.Timer();
        int totalSeconds = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tim.Interval = 1000; // 1 sec
            tim.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tim_Elapsed);
        }

        void tim_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // .....
            totalSeconds++;

            if (totalSeconds == 2) // 2 sec of wait
            {
                tim.Stop();
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("D:\\");

            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fsw.Filter = "file.exe";

            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

            fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);

            fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);           

            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }



        private  void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that a file has been changed

            WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;                
            MessageBox.Show("OnChanged File " + e.FullPath + wct.ToString());    
            tim.Start();// start timer as you get file.exe found....
        }

        private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that a file has been created

            WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;                
            MessageBox.Show("OnCreated File " + e.FullPath + wct.ToString());    
            tim.Start();// start timer as you get file.exe found....
        }

        private void OnDeleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that a file has been deleted.

            WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;               
            MessageBox.Show("OnDeleted File " + e.FullPath + wct.ToString());    
            tim.Start();// start timer as you get file.exe found....
        }

        //  This method is called when a file is renamed. 
        private  void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that a file has been renamed.

            WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;               
            MessageBox.Show("OnRenamed File " + e.OldFullPath + e.FullPath + wct.ToString());    
            tim.Start(); // start timer as you get file.exe found....
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you....

Comment: YES ! This is true :-) ...Really sorry for my Bad English..But this code Looks to Hard for easy Idea :-)

Comment: @Messiah1985 There is nothing hard in this sample code. It has simple `Timer` with event and `FileSystemWatcher` with its events. Please accept it if you find helpful to you.